# Greenplum Single Node fails on distributed files

Tags: postgresql

Running a Greenplum single node edition db, and I'm having errors with gpfdist.  Exact error message is:

ERROR:  connection with gpfdist failed for gpfdist://localhost:8080/facts_days1-3_out.csv. effective url: http://127.0.0.1:8080/facts_days1-3_out.csv. error code = 111 (Connection refused) (url.c:258)  (seg0 slice1 localhost:50001 pid=26618)

Does anyone have a recommendation for debugging this?

thanks,
mcpeterson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I ended up figuring this out.  I had two problems not displayed in the code unfortunately. I apologize for not showing them.

One:  I called the file with 
'gpfdist//localhost...
as opposed to
'gpfdist://localhost...

Which didn't register the file.  Secondly, I think my gpfdist process had died without me knowing it.  rerunning with:
./gpfdist -p 8081 -d mydirectory
and calling the external table from 8081 remedied the problem.

Best,
mcpeterson